# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Tags: jsp

I tried to get some value in drop-down from database by making Array List but when there is only one row in the database it gives the following error message

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

my code in jsp page is:

```
<% List<MedicalModel> SpecialityList= (ArrayList<MedicalModel>)request.getAttribute("speciality"); %>
<select name="SelectedDiagnosisID">
<% 
    for( int i=0; i<SpecialityList.size(); i++){   
%>
<option value ="<%=(SpecialityList.get(i).getDiagnosisID())%>"><%=(SpecialityList.get(i).getSpeciality())%></option>

<%}%>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unrelated to the issue, but when you call `request.getAttribute("speciality")` that could return `null` if this was not actually set in a request attribute of that name.  So you need to check for null before using the `.` operator on `SpecialityList`:

```
if(SpecialityList!=null)
{
   for(int i=0; i<SpecialityList.size(); i++)
   { 
       ...
   }
}
```

But your `for` look looks ok because  with this `for` loop, if your array is of size = 1,  you will only end up trying to access the index at 0, so you should not get a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` unless you somehow didn't put even one item in the array in the servlet where you are creating the array and setting it in the request attribute. So, the problem is probably with how you are putting the values into the array.